# How to move my database in localhost and php scripts to online

Tags: xampp

I built a mobile app for Online Employee Management System. I used PHP as my server side language and install xampp.

I built the entire app. But My doubt is how to move the localhost to some online web host. I mean, I just temporarily using ngrok for the temporary link and I am using that link in the app. How can I store the data in online and get the permanent link?

Comment: What specifically are you worried about?  Do you know know how to clone a DB?  Worried about DNS  switch over?  Worried about your code having issues?

Comment: I wrote the entire code and it works well. My only issue is I am using ngrok and getting the temporary link for my localhost and then I am running the app on my mobile. When the link expires, I need to again run the code with new link. How to avoid this ?? How to store my data in online and get the permanent link

Comment: That's what I'm asking?  Are you asking what the steps are to migrate a website?

Comment: you need to get an online host and connect the database to php code in that host. then build a web service and connect your web service to your app by libraries like retrofit or volley.

Comment: any free online host ??